# How to take an array of docs as condition to query then join with other table?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have three tables hold these docs:

```
//user----tables:users        
{
    Id:"user/001"   
    Name:"Jack Losen"    
    ....
}


//schooling---table:schoolings
{
     Id:"schooling/001"
     Name:""       
     Major:"",
     EnrollYear:1983
}

 //user_schooling-----join table:user_schooling
{     
     user_id:"user/001"
     schooling_id:"schooling/001"
}
```

How to take an array of schoolings as condition to query user ids by join table:user_schooling?

for example:if I want to get all ids of  the users who have been in A school at B year,or(not and) been in C school at D year...(or more),then my query condition may like this:

```
condition: [
          {
              Name:"A"       
              ....
              EnrollYear:B
           },
           {
              Name:"C"       
             ...
              EnrollYear:D
           }
       ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Guys in rethinkdb mail list gave right answer:

```
r.table('user_schooling').filter(function(row) { 
  return r.table('schooling').get(row('SchoolingId')).do(function(school) {
     return r.expr([{Name:"MASTER", EnrollTime:2003}]).pluck('Name', '
   EnrollTime').contains(school.pluck('Name', 'EnrollTime')); 
  });
}).pluck("UserId")
```